# How can I create a dummy variable over consecutive values by group id?

Tags: r

I have a data frame and some columns have NA values. In addition, the data is unbalanced (i.e. ID are over not the same years). I am trying to create a dummy variable (in R) over consecutive (over years) repeated values by group ID.

As an Example, I have a data.frame:

```
data <- data.frame(Year = c(1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993,
                            1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995),
                            ID = c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), 
                            value=c(0,0,0,NA,1, 0,1,0,1, NA,NA,0,0,0,0,1,0,0))
```

```
Year ID value
1  1980  1     0
2  1981  1     0
3  1982  1     0
4  1983  1    NA
5  1984  1     1
6  1990  2     0
7  1991  2     1
8  1992  2     0
9  1993  2     1
10 1987  3    NA
11 1988  3    NA
12 1989  3     0
13 1990  3     0
14 1991  3     0
15 1992  3     0
16 1993  3     1
17 1994  3     0
18 1995  3     0
```

I am interested in a new variable, say 'dummy', which is equal to zero if during 3 or more consecutive years value of variable 'value' is equal to zero, NA if value is NA, and rest one.
For example in the years 1980-1982 for the first ID, it should be zero, else 1 or NA, respectively.

What I am interested in is:

```
Year  ID  value  dummy
1  1980  1     0      0
2  1981  1     0      0
3  1982  1     0      0
4  1983  1    NA     NA
5  1984  1     1      1
6  1990  2     0      1
7  1991  2     1      1
8  1992  2     0      1
9  1993  2     1      1
10 1987  3    NA     NA
11 1988  3    NA     NA
12 1989  3     0      0
13 1990  3     0      0
14 1991  3     0      0
15 1992  3     0      0
16 1993  3     1      1
17 1994  3     0      1
18 1994  5     0      1
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **dplyr** to group your data by *ID*, sort your data by *ID* and *Year* to create the new variable. *Dummy* will be one, if and only if value (of this year for this person) and the value the year before and the one before are all equal to zero. Accordingly, ID1 in 1982 has dummy value of 0 in this example.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(ID, Year) %>%     ## sort by ID and year
  mutate(dummy = 
           case_when(
            value == 0 & lag(value, n = 1) == 0 & lag(value, n = 2) == 0 ~ 0, ## 3 consec years
            is.na(value) ~ value,  ## if value is NA
            TRUE ~  1 )            ## 1 otherwise
          )


# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
    Year    ID value dummy
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1980     1     0     1
 2  1981     1     0     1
 3  1982     1     0     0
 4  1983     1    NA    NA
 5  1984     1     1     1
 6  1990     2     0     1
 7  1991     2     1     1
 8  1992     2     0     1
 9  1993     2     1     1
10  1987     3    NA    NA
11  1988     3    NA    NA
12  1989     3     0     1
13  1990     3     0     1
14  1991     3     0     0
15  1992     3     0     0
16  1993     3     1     1
17  1994     3     0     1
18  1995     3     0     1
```

Comment: It was very useful. Thank you!